# iPhone rotate landscape

Tags: iphone, ios

i need a little help with iphone rotation in landscape mode the navigation bar is not being stretched

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage 
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage *barButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar-button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                          barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    UIImage *backButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,15,0,6)];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't write this code in this method.First of all you have to return Yes in the method -

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
```

And then you have to use :

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{ if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
// here your code
}
```